# ready jQuery after it's creation in a function

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function that writes a jQuery function for me, but when it comes time to run that jQuery (a click event), the code seems to have never `document.ready`ed it, because it wasn't there "in the beginning". How can I "ready" the code after it has been created by a function?

```
function readyclick(array){
    $("script").append("$(document).ready(function({
        $('#"+array+"').on('click', function(){$('#"+array+"').hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write it in following way to make sure your code executes correctly on document ready.

```
$(function(){
 //what evenr written inside this code will get executed on document ready

  // it seems you need to add some event. Usually events are added to HTML
  // controls and can be easily identified with help of ID or Name or Class
  // ++array++ does't seems name or id of any element. so check which html you 
  //want  to bind your event with. 
  // if it is a class write ".CLASS_NAME" if it is ID write "#Element ID"
   $("Your_element_selector").click(function(){
    / what ever you write inside this function will executed on click event of this element
     $(this).hide(); // you can access element using $(this);
    });

});
```

Comment: You were right! I was forgetting the "#". But it still won't execute when I click on it...

Answer (score 0):

I think after your "readyclick" function is done executing, you can simply do a

```
$.ready();
```

This should take care of executing the jquery code that is in the ready callback.

Comment: So I'm trying it, and maybe I'm just placing it wrong? Where would this go?